# Increase view width to the left and to the right

Tags: android, view, android-constraintlayout

I have the following layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/target"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LEFT VIEW"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RIGHT VIEW"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/left_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="LEFT"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right_btn"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/target" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/right_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="RIGHT"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/left_btn"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/target" />
```

Which result in this:
[image: result_layout]

This is the fragment:

```
public class IncreaseWidthLeftRightFragment extends Fragment {
    private IncreaseWidthLeftRightViewModel mViewModel;
    private TextView mRightView;
    private Button mLeftBtn;
    private Button mRightBtn;
    private TextView mLeftView;
    private ConstraintLayout mTarget;

    public static IncreaseWidthLeftRightFragment newInstance() {
        return new IncreaseWidthLeftRightFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.increase_width_left_right_fragment, container, false);
        mRightView = v.findViewById(R.id.right_view);
        mLeftBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.left_btn);
        mLeftBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showLeftText();
            }
        });
        mRightBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.right_btn);
        mRightBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showRightText();
            }
        });
        mLeftView = v.findViewById(R.id.left_view);
        mTarget = v.findViewById(R.id.target);
        return v;
    }

    private void showLeftText() {
        // increase the left side of the target container
        // ...
        mLeftView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void showRightText() {
        // increase the right side of the target container
        // ...
        mRightView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

The `left_view` and `right_view` TextViews are initially set to visibility `GONE`. The left button must show the `left_view` while expanding the left side but the right side should be kept in the same place. Similar for the right side but in the opposite direction.

How could I achieve this? I tried to play with the `LayoutParams` but without success. I would like to do this with an animation, but that will be the next step.

**UPDATE:**

Just to be clear, for instance, if I click on the left button, this should be the end result:

[image: end_result]

As you can see, the right side of the red rectangle is in the same X coordinate, however, the width of the rectangle increase to the left.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your problem a little bit? I can't see if your current approach affect left or right views place.

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev I have added an example of the result pretended. Is it clearer now? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need your target view be anchored with the text views, they should not be inside of it (supposing you want to use the `ConstraintLayout`). The text views themselves also should have some anchor on the layout, so they can expand related to it position.

#### 1) Add guidelines

For this purpose you can use [constraint guidelines](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline). E.g. if you want the text views (and consequently target view) expand from 32% from left and right edges of the root screen, you can add guidelines as follow (they should be at the same level of hierarchy with your buttons/target view):

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.32" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.68" />
```

*P.S. the `layout_constraintGuide_percent` always calculates from left side of a view the guide is inside of*

#### 2) Align your text views

As I said above, the text views should be at the same level with the target view, so grab them from inside the target view and put somewhere in the root constraint layout such that the right view is to right of the right guideline and left view is to left of the left one:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/left_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="LEFT VIEW"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/left_guideline" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/right_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RIGHT VIEW"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/right_guideline" />
```

We also need set vertical constraint for the views, and make a feeling that they are inside of the target view. In order to do that we need to align top side of both text views with the top side of the target view. In addition to that, the text views initial state should be "folded" (so they are hidden), unfortunately i don't know how to make them of width `0dp`, since such value for `layout_width` or `layout_height` makes a constraint layout think that the view just comply constraints instead of using it's own size. As a quick workaround let's set width to `1px`. To prevent the text views from extending vertically, i also would like to propose set `singleLine` property for them to `true`.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/left_view"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="1px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="LEFT VIEW"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/left_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/target" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/right_view"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="1px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RIGHT VIEW"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/right_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/target" />
```

#### 3) Align the target view

Now just align your target view left and right sides with left and right side of left and right text view respectively (so it's aligned with the outer boundaries of both text views) and set the `layout_width` attribute to `0dp`, that will make it follow constraints instead of plain values.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/target"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/right_view"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/left_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

#### 4) Add root layout id

In order to get root layout for animation, add id for the root layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

After all steps your layout blueprint should look like this:

[image: Layout blueprint]

*If you struggle at any step, feel free to use full layout gist from [here](https://gist.github.com/TheDreamsWind/4eae7668a63515025c40ccaf808348be).*

#### 5) Animate expanding

Eventually your show method should look something like that:

```
...
private void showLeftText() {
    expandView(mLeftView);
}

private void showRightText() {
    expandView(mRightView);
}

private void expandView(View view) {
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mRootView);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

And here is a short demo:

[image: Animation]